# How many endomorphisms from $K_4\rightarrow K_4.$

Tags: group-homomorphism

There are four elements in the Klein -4 group, with three elements non-trivial.

Order of all non-trivial elements is $2,$ and product of any two such elements is another.

The group table is:
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|} \hline
&e&x&y&xy\\ \hline
e&e&x&y&xy \\ \hline
x&x&e&xy&y \\ \hline
y&y&xy&e&x \\ \hline
xy&xy&y&x&e \\ \hline
\end{array}

For having endomorphism, need for any two elements $a,b\in K_4,$ need $\phi(a\times b)= \phi(a)\times \phi(b).$

The possible number of values of maps for pairs: $\phi(a), \phi(b),$ need be found for satisfying the homomorphism property.

First consider the trivial map of all elements mapping to $e.$
 0. $\phi(e)= 
\phi(x)= \phi(y)= \phi(xy)= e.$

Next, consider non-trivial homomorphisms, with $\times$ being the group operation of composition.

1. $\phi(e)=e,  
   \phi(x)=x, \phi(y)=y, \phi(xy)= xy.$
   Get, $\phi(x\times y)= \phi(xy)= xy= \phi(x) \times \phi(y).$
2. $\phi(e)=e,  
   \phi(x)=x, \phi(y)=x, \phi(xy)= e.$
   Get, $\phi(x\times y)= \phi(xy)= e=  \phi(x) \times \phi(y).$
3. $\phi(e)=e,  \phi(x)=x,\phi(y)=xy,\phi(xy)= y.$
   Get, $\phi(x\times y)= \phi(xy)= y = \phi(x) \times \phi(y).$
4. $\phi(e)=e,  \phi(x)=x, \phi(y)=e, \phi(xy)= x.$
   Get, $\phi(x\times y)= \phi(xy)= x = \phi(x) \times \phi(y).$

---

5. $\phi(e)=e, \phi(x)=y, \phi(y)=x, \phi(xy)= xy.$
   Get, $\phi(x\times y)= \phi(xy)= xy = yx = \phi(x) \times \phi(y).$
6. $\phi(e)=e, \phi(x)=y,\phi(y)=y, \phi(xy)= e.$
   Get, $\phi(x\times y)= \phi(xy)= e = \phi(x) \times \phi(y).$
7. $\phi(e)=e, \phi(x)=y,\phi(y)=xy,\phi(xy)= x.$
   Get, $\phi(x\times y)= \phi(xy)= x = \phi(x) \times \phi(y).$
8. $\phi(e)=e,  \phi(x)=y, \phi(y)=e, \phi(xy)= y.$
   Get, $\phi(x\times y)= \phi(xy)= y = \phi(x) \times \phi(y).$

---

9. $\phi(e)=e, \phi(x)=xy, \phi(y)=y, \phi(xy)= x.$
   Get, $\phi(x\times y)=  \phi(xy)= x=  \phi(x) \times \phi(y).$
10. $\phi(e)=e, \phi(x)=xy, \phi(y)=x, \phi(xy)= y.$
    Get, $\phi(x\times y)=  \phi(xy)= y = \phi(x) \times \phi(y).$
11. $\phi(e)=e, \phi(x)=xy,\phi(y)=xy,\phi(xy)= e.$
    Get, $\phi(x\times y)= \phi(xy)= e = \phi(x) \times \phi(y).$
12. $\phi(e)=e,  \phi(x)=xy, \phi(y)=e, \phi(xy)= xy.$
    Get, $\phi(x\times y)= \phi(xy)= xy = \phi(x) \times \phi(y).$

---

13. $\phi(e)=e, \phi(x)=e, \phi(y)=x, \phi(xy)= x.$
    Get, $\phi(x\times y)= \phi(xy)= x=  \phi(x) \times \phi(y).$
14. $\phi(e)=e, \phi(x)=e, \phi(y)=y, \phi(xy)= y.$
    Get, $\phi(x\times y)=  \phi(xy)= y = \phi(x) \times \phi(y).$
15. $\phi(e)=e, \phi(x)=e,\phi(y)=xy,\phi(xy)= xy.$
    Get, $\phi(x\times y)= \phi(xy)= xy = \phi(x) \times \phi(y).$

---

So, there are $16$ endomorphisms, as both $\phi(a), \phi(b)$have four choices each.
Hence, $4\star4=16.$

*Kindly vet the above.*

Comment: In general, a homomorphism can send generators to any elements which satisfy the same relations. In the Klein four group, the generators are defined by the fact they commute and square to the identity, so they can be sent to any two elements with the same property, which for the Klein-four group would be any two other elements. Kind of cumbersome to check all cases manually; we use logic and reasoning to get around having to use such brute force.